# Which Assembly version if not defined

Tags: .net, assemblies

Which version of an Assembly (.NET) is used by an application when a configuration file doesn't exist? I think it will be last one, but I can't find the proper documentation (msdn ...)!

Answer (score 0):

With no configuration present, the system will try to use the version specified in the CLR header of the application itself (which is created based on the target framework used when building the application).